# How to create a toggle button group

Tags: maui, maui-ios

I have this requirement that needs to have a toggle button which will switch to two different places. It looks something like this:

[image]

I've been trying to look for a control but it only shows `RadioButtonGroup` or `RadioButton`. Another suggestion is a `Switch` but it doesn't fit a requirement.

Any suggestions which I can do in order to make a toggle button group?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/gpproton/181a9263721be1dc6625ae44e1eccc19

Comment: there are numerous SegmentedControl implementations for Xamarin Forms that could easily be migrated to MAUI

Answer (score 0):

Just as Json said, you can create a custom SegmentedControl by yourself.

For this, you can refer to code [SegmentedControl](https://github.com/1iveowl/Plugin.SegmentedControl/tree/master/src/main/SegCtlr.Netstandard).

Though it is based on Xamarin.Form, but it is also apply to Maui.

You can also achieve this by creating a `ContentView` just as Jason said [here](https://gist.github.com/gpproton/181a9263721be1dc6625ae44e1eccc19). Or use [maui-segmented-control](https://www.syncfusion.com/maui-controls/maui-segmented-control) of syncfusion.